# Get Virtual Machine names in PowerShell via C# (Hyper-V)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to get the list of virtual machine names, from a local Hyper-V server, with the following code:

```
string _scr = ("Get-VM | Select -ExpandProperty Name");
var _ps = PowerShell.Create();
_ps.AddScript(_scr);
Collection<PSObject> _cObj = _ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject _vm in _cObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_vm);
}
```

The Get-VM cmdlet should return values in string format already, but I don't get any output.

I would like to get a result like the following output we get in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> Get-VM | Select -ExpandProperty Name
VM-Name1
VM-Name2
VM-Name3
VM-Name4
PS C:\>
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks a million.

Ada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-VM only works in a PowerShell session run as administrator. When I try your C# code run as an administrator it does print VM names.

When I try it without administrator rights I get no output, same as you - but there is an error reported if you check `_ps.HadErrors` it's `true`. Try this version of your code:

```
string _scr = ("Get-VM | Select -ExpandProperty Name");
var _ps = PowerShell.Create();
_ps.AddScript(_scr);
Collection<PSObject> _cObj = _ps.Invoke();

if (_ps.HadErrors) {
    Console.WriteLine(_ps.Streams.Error[0].ToString());
}

foreach (PSObject _vm in _cObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_vm);
}
```

I get "You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer {name}", you may get another error which gives you an idea what is going wrong.

(Another consideration, if the Hyper-V module is not being autoloaded you may need `Import Hyper-V;` at the beginning of your PowerShell code).